# How to get image bulge effect?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to correct an distorted image in Python.

The image is bulged out at the center like below image:

[image]

I want to correct the bulged image normal as much as possible.

I tried to solve it using the OpenCV library, but there is no good method. Is there any other library or solution to undistort bulged image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have tried `cv2.undistort()`, it works pretty well for the typical pinhole camera distortion you have. Check this page for the details:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/camera-calibration-with-opencv-f324679c6eb7